# squelize associations: query the last createdAt association from many to many association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

supose this schema:

```
var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
});

var status = sequelize.define('status', {
  status: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
});

var users_statuses = sequelize.define('users_statuses', {
    user_id: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
    status_id: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
});

user.hasMany(status, { foreignKey: 'user_id', through: models.users_statuses });
status.hasMany(user, { foreignKey: 'status_id', through: models.users_statuses });
```

So every user has many statuses (to keep track of all the selected statuses).
Using find with include, or the getter user.getStatuses() I can get all the statuses of an actual user, but I can't figure how to get the last/current associated status (based on the created_at column of users_statuses table/model)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick fix with 1 DB query. Use

```
user.find({
    where: {user_id : id },
    include: [{
        model: status,
        attributes: ['status']
    }],
    order: [ [ status, 'createdAt', 'DESC'] ]
}).then(function(user) {
    var latestStatus = user.status[0];
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But that will waste time getting all the statuses that you don't need. If you have many statuses, it is likely that Sequelize will waste more time truncating the results than if you were to do additional queries.

A better way is to search the `user_status` table for the latest `createdAt` status and do another query on the `status` table:

```
user_status.find({
    where: {user_id: yourid}
    order: [ 'createdAt', 'DESC']
}).then(function(user_status) {
    var latest_status_id = user_status.status_id;
    return status.find(where:{status_id: latest_status_id});
}).then..... catch....;
```

There is of course, the best way. But that will require you to associate the tables with its cross table and not let sequelize do that using the "through".

If your user_status is a strong entity, and it has the following relationship:

```
user_status.belongsTo(status, {foreignKey: status_id});
```

Then you can do:

```
user_status.find({
    where: {user_id: id},
    include: [{
        model: status
    }],
    order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC' ] ]
}).then....
```

The basic idea is that "includes" can only be used on strong entities. When you use `hasMany... through...`, the cross table is a weak entity and is not capable of having "includes".

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
.find({ limit: 1, order: 'updatedAt DESC' })
```

Comment: can't get your point. suppose `myuser = user.find(1, { include: [ status ]})` so `myuser.statuses` will return all the logged statuses what i want is only the last associated status

Comment: this is wrong answer. Find intrinsically has limit: 1